# AngularJS sharing data from service in controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to AngularJS and am trying to get a view to bind to some data I have retrieved in a service (factory) I have coded up like so:

```
app.factory('DataStoreService', function ($rootScope, $location, $http) {
    var lastReportedEvents = null;
    //For our inital request to server, but for subsequent requests we should use the nextURL 
    //property of the previous successful response 
    var locationStoreURL = '/location/GetLastReportedEvents.json';

    return {

        lastReportedEvents: lastReportedEvents,
        getLastReportedEvents: function () {
            $http.get(locationStoreURL)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    if (data.success) {
                        lastReportedEvents = angular.fromJson(data).data;

                        //TO-DO, use the nextURL property on the JSON response and set locationStoreURL var in this service

                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('getLocationData ERROR!');
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('getLocationData ERROR!');
                });

        }


    };

});
```

When the user logs in to the application I am making the request for data in the app run block like so.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'DataStoreService', function ($rootScope, $location, DataStoreService) {


      $rootScope.$on('login', function (event) {
          //console.log('login event detected');
          DataStoreService.getLastReportedEvents();
      });

  }]);
```

In my controller I have:

```
app.controller('LocationsController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'DataStoreService', function ($rootScope, $scope, DataStoreService) {

    $scope.locations = DataStoreService.lastReportedEvents;

}]);
```

So as you can see, I'm just trying to assign a property of my service that represents the data returned from the $http request to the $scope on my controller that my view is bound to:

```
<div ng-controller="LocationsController">

  <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr ng-repeat="location in locations">
        <td>
            <span>{{location.UnitName}}</span>
            <p>{{location.Location}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table >
</div>
```

Nothing appears in my view. I can get it to work by emitting an event in the success handler of my request and then assigning to the $scope in my controller in an event listener, but this seems a bit backwards to me. I thought by injecting a service to a controller, that any changes to the service (properties, etc) are broadcast to any controllers using that service, or am I mistaken.

I must be missing something fundamental here!

Thanks

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding , or i'm completely out of the way , but you fire the login event ( with $emit ) ?

Comment: Yes that's right. I have a login page bound to an authentication service and on a successful login I $emit a login event which as you can see gets picked up in the app run block

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Syarul

I have tried your approach but it did not work in my case

I actually found an answer by first initializing my lastReportedEvent to an empty array.

Then I changed this line from:

```
lastReportedEvents = angular.fromJson(data).data;
```

to:

```
lastReportedEvents.push.apply(lastReportedEvents, angular.fromJson(data).data);
```

The data is not available to my controller and my bound view is responding as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you wrote your service, but you need to return it to make it appear in controller.

```
return {
    lastReportedEvents: function () {
        $http.get(locationStoreURL)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.success) {
                    lastReportedEvents = angular.fromJson(data).data;
                    //TO-DO, use the nextURL property on the JSON response and set locationStoreURL var in this service
                    return lastReportedEvents;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('getLocationData ERROR!');
                }
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('getLocationData ERROR!');
            });
    }
};
```